# Mismatch in Assembly and Product Version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use Ajax control toolkit in asp.net website. I copied the dll from one of my previous sample project. It has the following details

```
Assembly Version – 3.5.40412.0
File Version - 3.5.40412.2
Internal Name: Ajax Control Toolkit
Language : Neutral
Product Version - 3.5.40412.2
```

When I add reference to this assembly, it appears as “AjaxControlToolkit-3.5.40412.2” in the reference list. When I run the solution, I get a FileLoadException:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit-3.5.40412.2' or one of its dependencies.
>
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I think the problem is with the difference in Assembly version and File version. Is it so? How can we overcome it?

Comment: try download a new copy from [codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/76976#DownloadId=304476)

Comment: That's not feasible in my work environment.

Comment: can you access the base dll of your previous project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the web.config file to remove the reference, which is not required for normal operation:

1 - Open the web.config file in the root of your site

2 - Find the following line and comment it out():xxxxx-is your assembly name.

```
<add assembly="xxxxx", Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

3 - Save and close the web.config file and try again

Ref Link :  http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-1118-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftwebservices3-version3000-cultureneutral-publickeytoken31bf3856ad364e35.aspx

Comment: I referred a different version of the dll from a different location and it worked well.