# Runtime error: Could not load file or assembly - Modules with different CPU types were found

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, .net-assembly

I'm getting the following runtime error in my WCF service.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After some looking around, I found a suggestion to use [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.90).aspx), or [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).  Neither or which yielded any information (that is, the log viewer showed nothing at all, and the process viewer didn't see the assembly load being attempted.

I finally came across a suggestion to use [this utility (dependency walker)](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to find out what the assembly was actually looking for.  On opening, I got an error immediately; and the log stated the following:

Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

```
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

According to the module list, it couldn't find these:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

Some of these look like they relate to the RT framework; however, this application was developed in .NET 3.5 (actually, that's not strictly true - it was developed in 4.5 and downgraded to 3.5).

Looking at some of these files seems to imply they are quite core Windows files, and oddly, I have used this dll elsewhere in the solution (admittedly on the client) without issue.

I'm using VS2013 although I've tried VS2012 and get the same issue.

I did come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems) which at first glance seems to be the same, although it relates to C++.

Can anyone give me some guidance as to what the issue might be, or what to try next?

Here is my fusion log:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyAssembly.MyLib.XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/myprog/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = myprog.exe
Calling assembly : System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\myprog\bin\Debug\myprog.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
```

I managed to reduce the library in question down until it was just a single static function that returns a string, and still get the error.

Comment: Dependency Walker hasn't been maintained in a long time, it is completely inadequate to diagnose this problem.  You will need to get Fuslogvw.exe going.  It will always provide a trace of this error if you use it correctly.

Comment: I maaged to get the fusion log and have updated the question

Comment: That was the 2nd failure, you need to find the entry for the original failure to load the assembly.  The original failure error code was a simple "file not found" error, very common of course.  Copying the file into c:\inetpub\MyServices\bin ought to bring some relieve.

Comment: The file is already there.

Comment: Update your trace with the first failure to get help.

Comment: I've managed to get the actual error log.

Comment: Are you mixing platform types? Try setting both assemblies' target platform to x86 (or x64). Make sure your build is clean (the output path per platform is unique and no other files lie there)

Comment: When you "downgraded to 3.5 how did you do that exactly? It may make more sense to recreate your project file(s) and re add the references to verify that the right version of the runtime .dlls are being used

Comment: Two questions: Is everything ok when opening your dll in reflector ? Are you changing current working directory at some point ? (debug=>breakpoint=>add : Environement.set_CurrentDirectory => will break if you do)

Comment: This link might solve your issue . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295614/mismatch-in-assembly-and-product-version/10330196#10330196

Comment: This link might help solving your problem.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295614/mismatch-in-assembly-and-product-version/10330196#10330196][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295614/mismatch-in-assembly-and-product-version/10330196#10330196

Comment: This link might solving your problem.

[mismatch-in-assembly-and-product-version][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295614/mismatch-in-assembly-and-product-version/10330196#10330196

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not using the WCF service from a website, but from a WPF desktop app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that always helped me with resolving this error was to take closer look at the part of the error message which says **"or one of its dependencies"**.

Comment: I've tried taking everything out, so that the library is basically a single static function that returns a string, and still get the error.

Comment: Well could you upload some isolated example?

Comment: I've rationalised the question a little.

Comment: I think this turned out to be the closest to an answer, so I'll award the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio with WCF has a quirk - if you build using a selected platform, it dumps the assembly in a platform-specific folder.  If you build with "Any CPU" it puts it in the root of your WCF's "Bin" folder.

When it configures IIS to help you?  It automatically assumes your assemblies will be in the root of that "Bin" folder.

The net event is that when you select "x86" instead of "Any CPU" you end up with the assemblies built in the wrong spot and suddenly your WCF does not run.  So this is one of the few rare cases where the catch-all error about not being able to load your file or assembly is telling the literal truth - Visual Studio put your assembly in the wrong place and now it can't find it.

I have no idea why they did it like that.  WCF has some... interesting design decisions.

Comment: I'm not building with x86 - everything is Any CPU

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple projects, it is possible some of them are not building when you run the application in Visual Studio. Right click on your solution, then go to Properties, Configuration Properties and confirm all the projects are set to compile.

Comment: They are, I also checked the build order and it's correct, and manually built the projects in the correct order, and physically verified that the library is, in fact, there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm not the only person that's been here.  I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone else:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f0c169f-c45e-4898-b2c4-f72c816d4b55/strange-xmlserializer-error?forum=asmxandxml

Just ignore the error... that how it's supposed to work!?

EDIT:

I've undeleted this answer for future reference.  I finally solved the problem.  It wasn't the issue above, it was an IIS problem specific to the solution I was working with.  There was a post build to copy compiled WCF binaries to a common location, but that obviously didn't include the new dependency.

I'll award to the closest answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the library that is part of your WCF service has one method and that is the problem method.

Can the method and it's reference be removed and does the runtime error go away?
It would be helpful if you could post the source to the project file and you should consider recreating the project file from scratch.

In that way if there are any stale references to 4.x they will be removed, please post more about your progress...

Comment: None of the library methods rely on a third party library correct?

Comment: So it really would have helped, if you had said for example only fails when deployed.

Comment: It wasn't deployed, it was all running locally on my PC

Answer (score 0):

I've always found that could not find is always because it is not there.
Sounds perhaps obvious but sometimes helpful to get the mind right => There is something which is not there.
Next well if you remember the principle of decoupling the definition from the implementation it goes to imply that your library containing the interface and the service should move to an external dll to the service.
 now that you've externalized the acting code, if that builds in itself, you've only the implementation left. Which being a downgraded solution a pragmatic approach is that the project has become 'funny'. 
Make  new project specific to your task an version and since it very likely only now contains reference to your library and a file with one line called something like thisismyservicename.svc as well as an address and a binding it should be pretty easy to copy the system.servicemodel part of your web.config. 
 Now you have nothing left in your original project and can flush is safely.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally given while project is developed in greater version of visual studio/Asp.Net and run/deployed machine has a lower version. Firstly check Visual Studio version of both machine.

Comment: As I said, I migrated from VS2012 to 2013 during dev of the project; however, it's all deployed and run on my machine, and I'm now exclusively running 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with wcf, I have the project working and after adding a wcf service it stop loading the svc file and the same issues, nothing worked for me, and at the end I removed the service and restart the machine, the rebuild everything and at the end I added the service again.