# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213

Tags: c#, dll, reference, version, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have Publish Project with reference of Ajax Version=4.1.7.1213 and deployed single page(Not ajax dll version 4.1) at Other machine (that machine having ajax version 1.0).

It shows me error like:Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213

But when I Publish again with reference of Ajax Version=1.0 and deployed same single page at Other machine (that machine having ajax version 1.0). Its work fine.

My question is When DLL get created after Publish is it stored reference of Ajax Version.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Edit the web.config file to remove the reference, which is not required for normal operation:

1 - Open the web.config file in the root of your site

2 - Find the following line and comment it out():xxxxx-is your assembly name.

```
<add assembly="xxxxx", Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

3 - Save and close the web.config file and try again

ref : [Mismatch in Assembly and Product Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295614/mismatch-in-assembly-and-product-version/10330196#10330196)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If your project is dependent on AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213 you should make sure that it is available on target machine.